# Set-id bits on an ISO

Tags: iso, suid, live-cd

I'm creating an ISO of a Debian system with:

```
mkisofs -V "Debian ISO" -cache-inodes -J -l -o file.iso debian-system/
```

The problem is: when I mount the ISO (`mount -o loop`) `ping` and `sudo` don't work because their suid bits have not been set.

I know that special bis are cleared by the `-r` flag. This flag generates the "rationalized Rock Ridge directory information" which enables to retain the original file permissions, but also clears any set-id bits.

But if I don't use `-r`, file permissions will be the same for all files, as specified at runtime when the ISO is mounted.

Question: how to add set-id files like ping and sudo to a linux "live" ISO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an alternate file system, that supports those permissions.

The way a LiveCD/DVD works is there is a squashfs file that is mounted with changes made in RAM.

You could "fake" the same by creating a file full of zeros using `dd`, make a file system on it wtih `mkfs.ext4`, mount it, and copy the files onto it.  Then on your custom disk, mount it as loop (`mount -o loop /path/to/file /mnt/point`) and symlink/etc the binaries over.

Comment: Sure, I don't need it to be an ISO absolutely. A "raw partition" in a file is a good idea. thanks!

Comment: ivanivan you need to edit your post so that the "-1" goes away (sorry for that it's a mistake I don't recall having clicked on "-1"). Because when I click "+1" the website replies "Your vote is now locked-in unless this answer is edited."